# Rotating image in matlab without cropping

Tags: image, matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am trying to rotate a square image in Matlab in various angles without cropping the central object and having black regions to increase my dataset for object recognition purposes.
Here is the original image:
[image: Original image]

With my current attempt,

```
function imF = my_im_rotate(img, angle)
    s   = ceil(size(img)/2);
    imP = padarray(img, s(1:2), 'replicate', 'both');
    imR = imrotate(imP, angle, 'bilinear', 'crop');
    S   = ceil(size(imR)/2);
    imF = imR(S(1)-s(1):S(1)+s(1)-1, S(2)-s(2):S(2)+s(2)-1, :); %// Final form
end
```

My result is:
[image]

A part of it is getting cropped. How do I prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the parameter `'crop'` to `'loose'`?

Comment: You are forcing the crop... By telling `imrotate` to `crop`. Read the documentation ;)